# Greek characters display issue Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, character-encoding

I am facing an issue in displaying greek characters. The characters should appear as `σ μυστικός αυτό?` but they are appearing as `ó ìõóôéêüò áõôü?`
There are some other greek characters which appear fine but the above text appears garbled.

The content is read from a HTML file using following code by a servlet:

```
public String getResponse() {
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
             try {
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fn), "8859_1")));
               String line=null;
               while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                  sb.append(line);
               }
               in.close();
               return sb.toString();
             }
            }
```

I am setting encoding as `UTF-8` while sending back response:

```
       PrintWriter out;
       if ((encodings != null) && (encodings.indexOf("gzip") != 1)) {
          OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
          out = new PrintWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(out1), false);
          response.setHeader("Content-Encoding","gzip");
       }
       else {
          out = response.getWriter();
       }
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
       out.println(getResponse());
```

The characters appear fine on my local development machine (which is Windows), but appear garbled when deployed on a CentOS Server. Both machines have JDK7 and Tomcat 7 installed.

Comment: Some causes I can think about: Are you sure you're getting ISO-8859-1 encoded chars from "fn"? when you render such characters, Is it in a browser? for some browsers you need to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` or, for HTML5: `<meta charset="utf-8">` even if you're sending the encoding in the HTTP header.

Comment: @morgano I have verified the encoding of HTML file is indeed ISO-8859-1 using `file -bi` command. The HTML file contains the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` too. Also, the characters appear fine if the HTML file is opened directly(not through servlet).

Comment: `file -bi` can't tell you whether your file is ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-7 (it is just a best-effort estimated), so I think @JimGarrison is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure the problem is your input encoding (when you read the data). You're decoding it as ISO-8859-1 when it's probably ISO-8859-***7*** instead. This would cause the symptoms you see.

The simplest way to check would be to open the HTML in a hex editor and examine the character encodings directly. If the Greek characters take up one byte each then it's almost definitely ISO-8859-7 (not -1). If they take up 2 bytes each then it's UTF-8.

From what you posted it looks like ISO-8859-7. In that character set, the lower-case sigma `σ` is `0xF3`, while in ISO-8859-1 that same code maps to `ó`, which matches the data you showed. I'm sure if you mapped all the remaining characters you'd see a 1-to-1 match in the codes. Maybe your Windows system's default codepage is ISO-8859-7?

Comment: I will check the encoding. But if the problem is with character set, then why does it appear fine when server is running on a Windows machine?

Comment: I can't guess until I know whether the file is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-7 but I'm now 99.999% sure it's the latter.  See my edit.

Comment: I think you are right. I matched character-by-character and it does seem the text is in `ISO-8859-7` encoding. Now my problem is there are several HTML files which are `ISO-8859-1`. Is there any "generic" way of reading the contents of files so that both `ISO-8859-1` and `ISO-8859-7` files are read correctly?

Comment: No. In order for the single-byte characters to get properly converted to UTF-16 (the internal Java representation) you have to tell the system the original encoding for each file individually when you open it.